# Yfinance works well on MAC but not on window

Tags: python, debugging, yfinance

I have just switched from Mac to window and I have try to run a few code to make sure everything is working. However when I am trying to use yfinance it won't run on window. It shows error

> 1 Failed download: - MT: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted

but the strange thing is it runs perfectly well on mac that's why I am confused.

```
start = datetime(2017,1,1)
end = datetime(2019,12,12)

ticker1 = yf.download('ticker1', start = start , end = end)
ticker2 = yf.download('ticker2', start = start , end = end)

print(stats.pearsonr(ticker1['Close'], ticker2['Close']))
```

The code is very simple and I don't understand what go wrong.

Comment: I have use a virtual envs don't know if that's the problem but I also use it on mac.

Comment: Don't add additional information in comments. use the [edit] button instead

Comment: can you share the full error message?

Comment: 1 Failed download:
- ticker: No data found for this date range, symbol may be delisted

Comment: for conda activation 
```conda : The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that 
the path is correct and try again.``` but I can activate conda in cmd but not in python shell